# Repetadly getting same bug

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've almost built one chat app with the login functionality using Firebase. But when I clear/delete all users from Firebase, uninstall app from my device and run the app from fresh and when it install and open app, it directly login it means it redirect to MainActivty instead of StartActivity where user can login or signup. I also faced this problem before and somehow I solved it, but again I improve the project, made some other classes and now again I'm facing the same problem.

Note:

1. When this things happens (automatically login), in my firebase database, it creates one ID automatically in under "Users" section. Actually it should happen only when user Singup.
2. I implemented the Facebook login button just before an hour, but this is not the issue, I'm sure about that, so please ignore Facebook login related stuff, this issue is getting before I implemented Facebook login button.
3. I tell you my app structure flow: When user first time install the app, it must redirect to StartActivity. If user already installed the app and login already, but not logout and simply closes the app and again open, it can login directly, it means it will redirect to MainActivity, no need to enter thr crendetials again.
4. Basically, my launcher activity is MainActivity, so if new user installed the app, it redirects from MainActivity to StartActivity (which is for login/singup).
5. LapitChat is a application class.

   **I'm attaching MainActivity.java, StartActivity.java, LapitChat.java, and AndroidManifest.xml**

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.jimmytrivedi.lapitchat;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ServerValue;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseUser currentUser;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private DatabaseReference UserDatabaseReference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if (currentUser == null) {
            sendTostart();
        } else {
            UserDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
            UserDatabaseReference.child("Online").setValue("true");
        }

        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.mainToolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");

        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (currentUser != null) {
            UserDatabaseReference.child("Online").setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
        }
    }

    private void sendTostart() {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, StartActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.logout) {
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
            sendTostart();
        }

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.settings) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class));
        }

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.allUsers) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, UsersActivity.class));
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

**StartActivity.java**

```
package com.jimmytrivedi.lapitchat;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button signup, exist;
    private CallbackManager mCallbackManager;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        signup = findViewById(R.id.signup);
        exist = findViewById(R.id.exist);

        signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(StartActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class));
            }
        });

        exist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(StartActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
            }
        });


        // Initialize Facebook Login button
        mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        LoginButton loginButton = findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile");
        loginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Log.d("wihddiewd", "facebook:onSuccess:" + loginResult);
                handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.d("wihddiewd", "facebook:onCancel");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Log.d("wihddiewd", "facebook:onError", error);
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser != null) {
            updateUI();
        }
    }

    private void updateUI() {
        startActivity(new Intent(StartActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Pass the activity result back to the Facebook SDK
        mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken token) {
        Log.d("wihddiewd", "handleFacebookAccessToken:" + token);

        AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.d("wihddiewd", "signInWithCredential:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            updateUI();
                        } else {
                            Log.w("wihddiewd", "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(StartActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                });
    }
}
```

**LapitChat.java**

```
package com.jimmytrivedi.lapitchat;

import android.app.Application;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ServerValue;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.squareup.picasso.OkHttp3Downloader;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class LapitChat extends Application {

    private DatabaseReference UserDatabaseReference;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);

        Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(this);
        builder.downloader(new OkHttp3Downloader(this, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        Picasso built = builder.build();
        built.setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
        built.setLoggingEnabled(true);
        Picasso.setSingletonInstance(built);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            UserDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());


            UserDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    if (dataSnapshot != null) {
                        UserDatabaseReference.child("Online").onDisconnect().setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jimmytrivedi.lapitchat">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:name=".LapitChat"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <service android:name=".FirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".StartActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".RegisterActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".StartActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".StartActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".StatusActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".SettingsActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat" /> <!-- optional (needed if default theme has no action bar) -->

        <activity
            android:name=".UsersActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".ProfileActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.jimmytrivedi.lapitchat_TARGET_NOTIFICATION" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ChatActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />

        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks for reading and waiting for your help. Thank you so much!

Comment: Please show your Manifest

Comment: Try by adding `android:allowBackup="false"` inside your `<application>` tag in Manifest

Comment: Please check the updated question. I added Manifest file and @Signo I'll try now and get back to you.

Comment: @Singo Thank you so much, it is working. BTW android:fullBackupContent="false" is also necessary? shoud I add manually? I didn't have any backup things in my xml file

Comment: @PriyankaSingh Glad it worked :) To be honest I'm not sure about the second property, it depends on where Firebase stores those informations in the device. Btw you might want to check this [answer](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/688) where it explains why this happens.

Comment: Yeah, I checked that answer. very helpful. Thanks for your quick help and observation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because from Android 6.0 (API level 23) the automatic backup is set by default to `true`. So to solve this, you need to add the following lines of code, in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
android:allowBackup="false"
android:fullBackupContent="false"
```

See [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup) more informations.

Comment: Thank you so much, it is working. BTW android:fullBackupContent="false" is also necessary? shoud I add manually? I didn't have any backup things in my xml file

Comment: Good to hear that it is working. Yes it is also necessary and you should add it manually. It is mandatory to also set it to false.

Comment: Oh, I was trying to upvote, but some error shwoing 15 reputation blah..balh... I did that acept answer, it turns into green. Thanks again.